# Python and Fabric Version compatibility

Tags: python, fabric, paramiko

I wrote a couple Python scripts that use Fabric which work on my laptop although when I recently shared it to my teammates they cannot fun the same file. They are able to run normal Python files but it does not seem to be picking up fabric. We both have Macbook OS X laptops and have Python 2.7.

My Fabric and Paramiko versions are:

```
Myhost$ fab -V
Fabric 1.10.2
Paramiko 1.15.3
```

While my coworker has and he is getting the below error when he tries to execute my fabric file:

```
Coworker$ fab -V
Fabric 1.13.1
Paramiko 2.1.1


$ python install.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "install.py", line 1, in <module>
from fabric.api import *
ImportError: No module named fabric.api
```

Does anyone know if these versions is causing this issue?

These are the commands we ran on his Macbook to install fabric:

```
1.) sudo easy_install pip
2.) pip install fabric
3.) pip install PyCrypto
4.) pip install -U pip setuptools
5.) pip install paramiko
```

Comment: Does your coworker have a file named `fabric.py` lying around in his working directory?

Comment: no, he doesnt. I have it set up with the main() so we can run it with python "fabric file"

Comment: it could be that your coworkers pip is not associated with the default python.
Run `head -1 $(which pip)` to see which python is used by pip and then compare with `which python`

Answer (score 0):

Your coworker could specify the version of fabric he would use by typing

```
pip install fabric==1.10.2
```

Which ensures you both have the same version!